# Facebook login button distorted

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I implemented the  Facebook registration on my website. Everything works fine except that suddenly the button is being rendering distorted. I'm testing the website locally.
[image]

this is the html code:

```
echo '<ul id="login_menu">
<li id="login_button"><a>Login</a></li>
<li class="register_button"><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
<li>  <fb:login-button registration-url="registerwithfb.php" /> 
</li>
</ul>';
```

javascript:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
                appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
                session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, // don't refetch the      session when PHP already has it
                status  : true, // check login status
                cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the   session
                xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

        // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
                window.location.reload();
        });
};

(function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

and css:

```
#login_menu{
float:right;
}
 #login_menu li{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:left;
  position:relative;
  }

   #login_menu li a{
   text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
   line-height:50px;
  text-decoration:none;
  height:55px;
   font-weight:900;
   font-size:13px;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color:#59b1da;
  }
 #login_menu li a:hover{
  color:#ffffff;

   }
```

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Which browser are you trying this with?

Comment: Can we see the HTML and CSS that produces that? (I suspect you're being downvoted as you've not supplied enough information to give a sensible answer). Also: what _should_ it look like?

Comment: @halfer you're probably right but I think people should motivate their downvotes. I accept being downvoted as long they tell me what I did wrong (like you did).

Comment: +1 for fixing the question. I moderately agree, but whether people ought to justify their downvotes is much disagreed upon at StackOverflow. So long as one learns from the justified ones, and ignores the occasional unjustified ones, it's all good.

Comment: I agree with @MrD - we might need CSS as well. Consider using jsFiddle, so that people can tweak your code very easily? (Edit: that said, I don't know if FB stuff will run from a non-recognised domain!)

Comment: it could be an issue with the li css definition, it would be really handy if you could copy the html from inside the browser once you load the page up as from this there's nothing really to look at?

Comment: Do you get the same problem in Firefox/Chrome/IE etc?

Comment: Also comment out #login_menu li a and see what happens?

Comment: @halfer I'm having the same problem also with all the above browser.

Comment: Try putting the above on a plain page with no other CSS - I'm wondering if you've got some other CSS with specificity problems.

Comment: @MrD A huge thank you! that was the problem.... can you please answer the question so I can Accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment out #login_menu li a

as it may have been interfering. Glad I could help.